# Grep fails to find sequence after assign to variable

Tags: bash, grep, environment-variables, echo

I run:

```
awk -F ',' '{print $2}' data.dat | sort | uniq |  tr '\n' ',' | grep "*)>nS4XkrlH  @XUL"
```

and the sequence is located in results.

Then I run

```
b=`awk -F ',' '{print $2}' data.dat | sort | uniq |  tr '\n' ','`
echo $b | grep "*)>nS4XkrlH  @XUL"
```

but no result is returned.

Does anyone have any ideas on why this happens?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key key difference between those two command sequences is that the second contains `echo $b` which performs shell *word splitting*.  To make the second command sequence run the same as the first, replace:

```
echo $b | grep "*)>nS4XkrlH  @XUL"
```

with:

```
echo "$b" | grep "*)>nS4XkrlH  @XUL"
```

#### Word Splitting

Observe how spaces are treated in these two `echo` statements:

```
$ b="a   b c"
$ echo "$b"
a   b c
$ echo $b
a b c
```

Without the double-quotes, the shell performs word-splitting on the arguments to `echo`.  This means that all consecutive whitespace is condensed to a single space.  With double-quotes, word splitting is suppressed and the whitespace is preserved.

#### Word Splitting and a `grep` Pattern with Multiple Spaces

Your `grep` pattern contains two consecutive spaces.  Unless the argument to `echo` is in double-quotes, the output of `echo` will not have those two spaces and no match will be found.  Observe:

```
$ b="*)>nS4XkrlH  @XUL"
$ echo $b | grep "*)>nS4XkrlH  @XUL"
$ echo "$b" | grep "*)>nS4XkrlH  @XUL"
*)>nS4XkrlH  @XUL
```

The first `grep` does not match on anything but the second does.  The difference is the shell's word splitting.

Comment: You are correct! The explanation was very good.